# How to avoid overwriting data in a txt file with rust

Tags: rust

Hey so I'm attempting to make a small program and I want it to have some logs. The issue is that it runs in a for loop and it keeps overwriting the old data written to it. Looking around there might be a fix with ".append()" but I cant seem to find a way to get it working. If I could get some help that would be greatly apricated.

```
            let download_dir = Path::new(download_dir);
            fs::create_dir_all(download_dir).unwrap();
            fs::rename(&path, download_dir.join(file_name)).unwrap();

            let log_dir = "Logs";
            fs::create_dir_all(log_dir).unwrap();

            let mut file = std::fs::File::create("logs/Logs.txt").expect("create failed").append(true);
            
            file.write_all(format!("{:?}", file_name).as_bytes()).expect("write failed");
            file.write_all(format!(" Moved to ").as_bytes()).expect("write failed");
            file.write_all(format!("{:?}\n", download_dir.display()).as_bytes()).expect("write failed");
```

Output

```
"t3.png" Moved to "Pictures"
```

Expected

```
"t1.png" Moved to "Pictures"
"t2.png" Moved to "Pictures"
"t3.png" Moved to "Pictures"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the file in append mode.  You can do this with [`OpenOptions`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html#):

```
let mut file = std::fs::OpenOptions::new()
    .append(true)
    .create(true)
    .open("logs/Logs.txt")
    .expect("create failed");
```

Comment: Ahh sorry I didn't know about "OpenOptions" your solution worked!